# htaccess redirect all links that have {{link}} to same link without that string

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, seo

From some unknown reason, Google has indexed many pages on my website with a weird {{link}} as part of the url. Most of the times it is a copy of the same page without that weird string, but this duplicated content is concerning.

How can I redirect all urls that include the string "{{link}}" to the same url, just without the {{link}} ?

Comment: could you tell us one of your indexed url?

Comment: @mehdi added in comment to answer below. any idea on how this could have happened are also super welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/\{\{link\}\}\_(.*)$ /$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: @Noam Try this for the last time, I tried it and it actually worked.